# Getting the sum of second column plus rows in first column where second column is empty

Tags: excel

I have this setup in my worksheet

```
First   Second
1       6
2   
3       7
4       8
5
```

and i need to do the following in a single cell

1. SUM of all numbers in ["Second" column] + [rows in "First" column where "Second" column is empty]

Is it possible to do all of this in a single cell? without having to create a 3rd column to fill in the blanks for the second column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use two SUMIF:

```
=SUMIF(B:B,">0")+SUMIF(B:B,"=",A:A)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or one `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A6*(B2:B6="")+B2:B6)
```

[image]